# Multiple nested IF in Excel issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the attached sheet, in column J (FOLLOW-UP REQD.?), my requirement is as follows:

If Column G (Status) is blank, that is, not ‘Closed’, then, the formula should refer to the Column I (COUNT OF DAYS).

If the No. of Days is greater than a number, say, 75, then, it displays the text, ‘Follow-up reqd’.

However, if the entire row itself is blank, and hence both the fields, STATUS, as well as COUNT OF DAYS are blank, then field FOLLOW-UP REQD.?  also should remain blank.

I am struggling with the formula to achieve this which I have put in cell J8. However, this is giving an error.  How do I correct this, to fulfill all conditions?

Additionally, in the same formula, can I incorporate a condition, which states if STATUS = Closed, then too, FOLLOW-UP REQD.? field to remain blank?
Thanks.[SAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWSh8.png)

I have tried to use the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(G8),ISBLANK(I8)),"", ELSEIF(AND(ISBLANK(G8),I8\>75),"FOLLOWUP"))
```

Comment: You are mixing the macro/VBA function [IF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements) with the worksheet function [IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2#:~:text=Use%20the%20IF%20function%2C%20one,another%20value%20if%20it's%20false.&text=For%20example%3A,B4%2DA4%2C%22%22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Nested *If* Statements

[image]

**In cell `J4` (Copy Down)**

```
=IF(G4="Closed","",IF(I4="","",IF(I4>75,"Follow-up reqd",I4)))
```

**In cell `J4` (Spilling)**

```
=IF(G4:G9="Closed","",IF(I4:I9="","",IF(I4:I9>75,"Follow-up reqd",I4:I9)))
```